# Inserting SQLite rows via Ruby iteration

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

Inserting 5 rows of 4-column data into an existing SQLite db, and I get these errors...

```
/Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize': near "tagline": syntax error (SQLite3::SQLException)
        from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
        from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
        from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
        from insert_code_sam.rb:60:in `block in <main>'
        from insert_code_sam.rb:59:in `times'
        from insert_code_sam.rb:59:in `<main>'
```

Here are last lines (59-61) from my .rb file:

```
    5.times do
      db.execute('INSERT INTO index1 (name tagline blurb photo_url) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', ["name", "tagline", "blurb", "photo"])
    end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Added return (/n) to code block to read easier.

Comment: Are you opposed to using the wonderful, convenient [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) library? It makes so many SQL-related tasks a snap.

Comment: @Phrogz thanks for the link. I just skimmed the README and it looks helpful; I'm on a deadline now so will peruse later. I'm also a SQL noob so want fundamentals under my belt. Would using Sequel take away from this endeavor you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have a small syntax error in your SQL. The column list for an INSERT should be comma delimited:

```
INSERT INTO index1 (name, tagline, blurb, photo_url) ...
                        ^        ^      ^
```

so your Ruby should look like this:

```
5.times do
  db.execute('INSERT INTO index1 (name, tagline, blurb, photo_url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', ["name", "tagline", "blurb", "photo"])
end
```

See the "column-name" loop in the [SQLite INSERT syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) diagram:

[image]

Comment: +1 for adding their railroad diagrams. There are many great things about SQLite, and many sub-optimal things, but those diagrams are just plain awesome.

Comment: Perfect! It works. Thanks again @mu!   @Phrogz diagram is awesome indeed. Found the original googling sqlite insert syntax.

Comment: @Phrogz: I'm pretty happy with the SQLite documentation overall, the diagrams are particularly useful syntax summaries.

Comment: FYI, I just learned that another term for placeholders mu is using is "sanitation replacement."